# How to prepare google map api request with waypoints from java

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to prepare a following URL from java using `com.google.maps` google library. I am not finding proper library methods to add waypoint. Please let me know how to add waypoints to google map api.

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=17.4366668,78.3982614&destination=17.42955,78.34171&waypoints=via: 17.44027,78.39431|via:17.43149,78.38817&key=AIzaSyDhhwfZgJv4DCVuX-RDuXLXfoHWL6FIPAw](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=17.4366668,78.3982614&destination=17.42955,78.34171&waypoints=via:%2017.44027,78.39431%7Cvia:17.43149,78.38817&key=AIzaSyDhhwfZgJv4DCVuX-RDuXLXfoHWL6FIPAw)

I am following below approach to add origins and destinations to *GeoAPi* context.

```
GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext();
    context.setApiKey("AIzaSyDhhwfZgJv4DCVuX-RDuXLXfoHWL6FIPAw");

    LatLng originLatLng = new LatLng(17.4366668,78.3982614);

    LatLng destinationLatLng = new LatLng(17.42955,78.34171);

    LatLng wayPoints = new LatLng(17.4477, 78.38264);


    DirectionsResult result = DirectionsApi.newRequest(context)
            .origin(originLatLng)
            .destination(destinationLatLng)
            .waypoints("17.44027,78.39431", "17.43149,78.38817")
            .await();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find the method for waypoints in source code on Github:

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/maps/DirectionsApiRequest.java

Starting from line 151:

```
/**
* Specifies a list of waypoints. Waypoints alter a route by routing it through the specified
* location(s). A waypoint is specified as either a latitude/longitude coordinate or as an address
* which will be geocoded. Waypoints are only supported for driving, walking and bicycling
* directions.
*
* <p>For more information on waypoints, see <a href="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Waypoints">
* Using Waypoints in Routes</a>.
*/
public DirectionsApiRequest waypoints(String... waypoints) {
  if (waypoints == null || waypoints.length == 0) {
    return this;
  } else if (waypoints.length == 1) {
    return param("waypoints", waypoints[0]);
  } else {
    return param("waypoints", (optimizeWaypoints ? "optimize:true|" : "") + join('|', waypoints));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the waypoints method taking a string of waypoint name, in my case I have lat and long of waypoints. Not sure how to pass?

Comment: I think you can pass them as strings. The code in your question seems good to me. This string will be inserted in the HTTP request as is. So you can pass "17.44027,78.39431" or "via:17.44027,78.39431". You can see that the source code of waypoints method joins these strings with a pipe symbol.

Answer (score 0):

The waypoints params could be pass with LatLng. Here is sample of code that working for me:

```
DirectionsResult result = DirectionsApi.newRequest(context)
                .mode(TravelMode.DRIVING)
                .origin(new LatLng(-7.372732, 110.50824))
                .waypoints(new LatLng(-7.272732, 110.508244), new LatLng(-7.172732, 110.508244))
                .optimizeWaypoints(true)
                .destination(new LatLng(-7.372732, 110.508244))
                .awaitIgnoreError();
```